# how can i publish swagger doc generated by springfox as part of the build process

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

We are using springfox to generate swagger docs for our springboot application at runtime. We would like to publish these somewhere as part of our jenkins pipeline. Is there a way to generate these static docs as part of the build that we can then export in the pipeline?

Comment: You know that Jenkins can just execute commands? So any command that you would run locally to generate them can be executed in the pipeline as well, like running a certain maven goal. Do you know how to generate the docs in general?

Comment: no, that's what i'm trying to figure out. all i can find is the runtime doc in springfox.

Comment: Okay, then it's but a Jenkins question